# Data model in child component

Tags: meteor, reactjs, components, communication, meteor-react

I would like to know what the best practice is for a communication between parent/child components. I have read this [blogpost](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/03/24/best-practices-for-component-state-in-reactjs.html) about communication and components states but haven't found the right answer for my problem.

Following components are considered.
My parent component is a List, which renders several Tasks (child component) from objects in the parent component.

So my questions are:

1. Is it best practice to pass the object to each Task component?
2. When a value has changed in the Task component, how does the parent component know about this? Because the parent should know about the infos of all children.

So is this a right pattern to use?

In my Parent Component I have this in the render function:

```
<Task key={index} taskdata={taskobj} />
```

My Task child component looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (
         <input type="text" name="wunsch" defaultValue={this.props.task.title}/>
);
}
```

So if the value of the input field will change, does taskobj in the parent component also change? In this example no. But what would be the right pattern here?

Comment: Can you provide code example for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you want to pass information from parent to children you use `props`, when you want to pass information from child to parent you pass a function to a child as a `prop` and then call it when you need to update a parent.

You can read more in [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)

Also you can take a look [Reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs).
A simple library for unidirectional dataflow architecture inspired by ReactJS Flux

Comment: Is there a way that the information in the parent component will update automatically when the child information has changed? Like the "state" mechanism?

Comment: A key React concept is to provide one way data flow architecture. You can use some libraries to create two way bindings. I would recommend to take a look at https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs. You can create an action and subscribe as many components to this action and all of them would be updated when you call this action.

Answer (score 1):

> In React, data flows one way

I wasn't really aware of this React concept.
So after reading this [link](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) in the ReactJS Doc I decided to the onChange/setState() way as ReactLink is already deprecated.

So when a change in the model happens in the child component I call a method in the parents component to update (setState) my data.